# How to make the grid polygons assume the inside centroid attributes of another layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, vector-grid, centroids

I have a square grid and I have multiple centroids on another layer. These centroids have many attributes as values. I want for each grid cell to assume the attributes of the centroids inside them. For example, if a grid has two certain centroids inside it, I want the grid to get the sum of the values for each attribute from each centroid inside it (i.e. if centroid 1 has A=3 and B=2, and centroid 2 has A=2 and B=5, the grid cell should have the attribute values of A=5 and B=7). How can I do this ?
I use the last version of QGIS (3.28).

[image: grid centroid print]

Comment: How do you want to solve this? Through any software or programming? Kindly specify.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.28. I'm trying to know if there is anyway to do this through QGIS.

Comment: The tool *Join attributes by location (Summary)* should do what you need.

Comment: @Matt I tried your suggestion, but what happens is that the new Joined layer creates a cell grid for each centroid (instead of joining every centroid information in one unique cell). I tried solving this by using Dissolve by the same cell ID, but it doens't sum the attribute values, instead it just uses the value of one of the centroids (instead of summing the values from all the centroids inside the cell). Any suggestion ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to switch the tool inputs. The parameter "Join to features in" should be the grid, and "By comparing to" should be the points layer. It will return as many features as are in your grid layer.

Comment: That is how I did it. The problem is that i doesn't sum the values of the centroids inside the cells, instead it creates different cells in the same place (overlapping) with each having the value of one centroid. For example a cell with ID: 1480 has 3 centroids, each centroid has different values of N. What I wanted, is that after the process, I would have the cell with ID: 1480 with the attribute N having a total value of the sum of the 3 centrois (N1+N2+N3). Instead, I get 3 overlapping cells with ID: 1480, each cell having the value of either N1, N2 or N3 (and not the sum as itended).

Comment: And when I dissolve the cells with the same ID, for example the 3 cells with ID: 1480, I get only one cell with the ID: 1480, but instead of adding the values N1,N2 and N3, I only get one of these values.

Comment: If you use the GDAL dissolve in Processing you have advanced parameters which include summing attribute values.   There is also an aggregate tool that you might look at.

Comment: @John I tried that now and I got these errors:

GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry, "fid" FROM "INPUT" GROUP BY "fid"): 
no such column: geometry
Process returned error code 1

The following layers were not correctly generated."

Comment: You might try running an Intersect of your points and grid after making sure each layer has a field with a unique attribute value.  Then you could try some different approaches including running the GDAL dissolve on the points,  running the Aggregate tool on them, or exporting their table for use in Excel to run a pivot table on the data.  Then join your work, however done, back to the Grid layer using the grid ID.  The latter two approaches allow you to concatenate values or do other statistical analysis beyond summing.

Comment: Using *Join attributes by location (Summary)* the way I described gave me exactly the result you are after when I tested.

Comment: @Matt you were right all along, It worked simply and fantastically. It was my mistake, I was using Join attributes by location (without the Summary), sorry for that. Thank you everyone for your time and help!

Comment: No problem :) easy mistake to make. I'm glad you achieved what you needed in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Credit: @Matt user:128665

Answer: Using Join attributes by location (Summary)

Note: the answer was already in the comments, but at the time, this question was closed